# FCM This site has been updated in the background

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

So I'm using VueJS with the PWA option enabled. When using Firebase Cloud Messaging (for web app), I'm getting a notification saying: `This site has been updated in the background` but Only when the tab is not focused or open. If the tab is active, I don't receive anything in the console.
I'm using Postman to send notifications for now, and it returns success

```
{
    "multicast_id": 5364665067527599460,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1550148053476716%2fd9afcdf9fd7ecd"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my `main.js`

```
const config = {
    apiKey: "API_KEY",
    authDomain: "AUTH_DOMAIN",
    databaseURL: "DATABASE_URL",
    projectId: "PROJECT_ID",
    storageBucket: "STORAGE_BUCKET",
    messagingSenderId: "SENDER_ID"
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

const messaging = firebase.messaging();
messaging.usePublicVapidKey("PUBLIC_VAPID_KEY");
navigator.serviceWorker.register('./firebase-messaging-sw.js')
  .then((registration) => {
    console.log("Now using registration: " + registration);
    messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

  }).catch(err => {
    console.log("Error in registration");
    console.log(err)
  });
```

My `firebase-messaging-sw.js` (I never saw the console log thats inside `setBackgroundMessageHandler`)

```
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase-app.js');
importScripts('https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.8.2/firebase-messaging.js');

var config = {
  messagingSenderId: 'SENDER_ID'
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

let messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
  console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);

  return self.registration.showNotification('title', {body: 'message'});
});
```

And in my `App.vue` (neither have I ever seen the console log in `onMessage`)

```
created() {
    this.$messaging.onMessage(function(payload) {
        console.log('Message received: ', payload);
        // ...
      });
},
methods: {
    sendNotif() {
        this.$messaging.requestPermission().then(() => this.$messaging.getToken())
        .then((token) => {
            console.log(token) // Receiver Token to use in the notification
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log("Unable to get permission to notify.", err);
        });
    },
},
```

I can access the token, none of my configuration is wrong or else the postman request wouldn't give success. I've checked out several other questions related to this but no success so far...

Comment: Hi Adam. I have a problem with this message, but it is when tab is focused. In this case, I receive same message but, when not focused, it works. First of all, you don't need to register a service worker if the name is the default (firebase-messaging-sw.js). You just need to keep this file in same folder. On the console, can you see something? I am asking on both scenarios (tab focused and not focused)...